# Proof of Hensel's Lemma (particular version)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ an odd prime number which do not divide $a$. We suppose that there is a solution $u_k$ to the equation $x^{2} \equiv a [p^{k}]$. Then, there is only one solution $u_{k+1}$ to the equation $x^{2} \equiv a [p^{k+1}]$ and $u_{k+1} \equiv u_k [p^k]$.

Here is my attempt :

***Analysis*** : We suppose that we found $u_{k+1}$ :

According to the hypothesis we have $u_{k+1} \equiv u_k [p^k]$ $\Rightarrow$ $u_{k+1}=lp^{k}+u_k$ $\Rightarrow$ $u_{k+1}^{2}=p^{k}(l^{2}p^{k}+2lu_{k})+u_{k}^2$

Moreover we also have : $u_{k+1}^{2} \equiv a [p^{k+1}]$ $\Rightarrow$ $u_{k+1}^{2}=l'p^{k+1}+a$ $\Rightarrow$ $u_{k+1}^{2}=(l'p)p^{k} +a$ $\Rightarrow $ $u_{k+1}^{2} \equiv a [p^k]$

So we found a form for $u_{k+1}$ but it is not necessary unique.

***Synthesis*** : For $u_{k+1}$ which has been found :

$u_{k+1}^{2}=p^{k}(l^{2}p^{k}+2lu_{k})+u_{k}^2 \equiv a[p^{k}]$ (I think it is not sufficient).

But I don't know how to get $u_{k+1}^{2}\equiv a[p^{k+1}]$

For unicity no problem.

So I was wondering if I'm on the right way ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a key assumption. You must have $a$ non-zero mod $p$; else everything falls apart. This is the condition in Hensel's lemma that says if we're trying to lift a root $\alpha$ of a function $f$ mod $p$, we need $f'(\alpha) \neq 0$ mod $p$. (This is where we get annoying cases where we can't apply Hensel's lemma; for example, when studying quadratic forms, we can basically never apply Hensel's lemma for $p = 2$. Indeed, this is also why we work only with odd primes here, as the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$, so mod $2$ the derivative always vanishes).

Assuming this, once you've picked $u_k$ above, then square it to get 
$$u_{k+1}^2 = p^k(l^2p^k + 2lu_k) + u_k^2 \equiv 2p^klu_k + u_k^2 \mod{p^{k+1}}.$$
(You missed off the square on the $u_k$, but I assume that's just a typo!). So setting $u_k^2 = a + mp^k$ mod $p^{k+1}$, you're looking to solve
$$p^klu_k + a + mp^k \equiv a \mod{p^{k+1}},$$
that is, you're aiming to pick $l$ such that
$$2p^klu_k + mp^k \equiv 0 \mod{p^{k+1}}$$
which holds if and only if
$$2lu_k + m \equiv 0 \mod{p}.$$
Can you now see why the condition is necessary?

(More generally, when working with more general functions $f$, we look at Taylor expansions of $f(u_k + lp^k)$. It just so happens that in the case of $f(x) = x^2$, this Taylor expansion works out to be precisely expanding the brackets!)

Comment: Did you made it with analysis-synthesis process because I thought that we have to prove that the form of $u_{k+1}^2 \equiv a [p^{k+1}]$ during the synthesis step ?

Comment: The idea is that you construct $u_{k+1}$ to have the properties you desire. So for it to satisfy $u_k \equiv u_{k+1} \mod p^k$, we know we have $u_{k+1} = u_k + lp^k$, as you've written. You then want to show that there is a unique $l$ such that $u_{k+1}^2 \equiv a \mod p^{k+1}$, which is what I've described above. For arbitrary $l$ there's no hope of proving that $(u_k + lp^k)^2 \equiv a \mod p^{k+1}$, as it's only true of one specific $l$!

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the unicity of $l$

Comment: In the calculations I gave above, we showed that $l$ works if and only if $2lu_k + m \equiv 0 \mod p$, for fixed values of $u_k \neq 0 \mod p$ and $m$. So $l = -m/2u_k \mod p$, and this is the unique solution (where $2u_k$ is invertible as $p$ is odd and $u_k$ is non-zero mod $p$ by the assumption in Hensel's lemma).

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand now. However I think you missed a $2$ just after"solve" in your answer

Comment: The condition of "$a$ non-zero mod $p$ is also used in Lagrange's theorem on polynomial equations ?